# Can't find nether warts

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been exploring in the nether for Nether Warts and I already found 2 fortresses but it seems that there is no Nether Wart in both the fortress.

I know it is in a room with stairs in the middle of the room and soul sands beside the staircase but I can't find any room similar to this.

How can I get Nether Wart without the Nether Fortress? Is it possible to get them through the Wizards (as in villagers that have potions)?

Comment: Very late response but for anyone who reads this post in the future, villagers don't sell potions. Fletchers sell tipped potion arrows, though. But they aren't called Wizards ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Nether wart sometimes generates naturally in nether fortresses as a plant, in patches near stairwells.

Seems as though you are really just unlucky. They have a chance of spawning near every stairwell

> Nether wart can be found in 19.0% of fortress chests in stacks of 3–7.

You may also find them in chests in the fortress

Source:https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Wart

Comment: Thanks! I was able to find 5 nether wart in one of the chests. Now I got to farm these and make some potion!